# is it possible to develop games with Unity Game Engine on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi

I am interested in game development, but my main computer is a raspberry pi 4B, and I won't be upgrading for a while. I am hoping to upgrade eventually, but for now I would like a solution for running Unity Engine on my Raspberry Pi 4B. performance is not my worry, I am overclocking to 2ghz and am using a lightweight desktop. I will only be doing 2d on my pi, but I want to use unity so that i don't have a massive learning curve  when I hopefully upgrade and am able to do 3d.
Thanks!

Comment: 2D or 3D does barely matter .. 2D is the same Unity etc just setting the camera to orthographic ...

Comment: Im not sure the pi has enough to meet minimum rubning of unity. Why dont you try it to find out

Comment: but if the Raspberry Pi is ARM, will it run even on ubuntu? I thought appimages will only run on a specific processor type, and the unity hub is x86 not arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it should be possible since Raspberry PI supports the Ubuntu Desktop operating system and so does Unity. Though, I haven't personally tested this out.

So that means that you would need to install `Ubuntu` on your Raspberry PI device and then install `Unity Hub` and then a version of the `Unity editor`.

### Sources:

[Operating systems supported by Raspberry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#third-party-software) 
[Linux distributions supported by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html#:%7E:text=Unity%20officially%20supports%20the%20following,CentOS%207)